# In the third mission of Modern Times I ran out of gold and have to export

Tags: tropico-4

In the third mission of the Modern Times campaign, I get the objective to export gold, yet, since my strategy always is start with boat loads of mines, I already mined ALL the gold on the island, so I have nothing left to export.
Is there a way to still finish the objective or do I have to restart?

Comment: fwiw you can try playing with different strategies (farming, oil, etc).  Most of them work pretty well though I always have the hardest time relying on tourism.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe it would be possible to import some gold, then switch back to exporting that gold. But you'll be losing a lot of money in the process and it won't be easy.

I'd suggest restarting, really. I don't like it either, but you sometimes find better ways to do things by rebuilding :-)

Comment: I tried doing that, I import 500 units of gold by putting my Jewelry factory on active, and as soon as they are delivered I fire all workers from it, but I haven't seen it export any additional gold (tried it 3 times already)

Comment: I don't see any other way to export gold, if not by local mining or first importing it (hacking/trainers/etc excluded). So I would suggest starting again.

Answer (score 1):

This is years late but this thread came top when i was looking for an answer.

I solved this problem by importing gold, locking imports and firing workers THEN demolishing the factory, seems the resources get exported.

Hope this helps somebody.